# Executable not found, only when deploying on azure via terraform

Tags: azure, docker, terraform, azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure

When deploying my web app on azure via terraform the following error message is displayed in the deployment logs in the azure portal.

```
2023-09-28T11:43:21.777Z INFO - latest Pulling from censored-user/censored-app-v1
2023-09-28T11:43:21.788Z INFO - 445a6a12be2b Already exists
2023-09-28T11:43:21.819Z INFO - d0cea56d3b74 Already exists
2023-09-28T11:43:21.823Z INFO - e2556305f3e2 Already exists
2023-09-28T11:43:21.825Z INFO - e2556305f3e2 Already exists
2023-09-28T11:43:22.546Z INFO - Digest: sha256:e17ed63b24b560768925aed0c653a554ba769a804277a8f22bace8816db2434e
2023-09-28T11:43:22.548Z INFO - Status: Downloaded newer image for censored-user/censored-app-v1:latest
2023-09-28T11:43:22.562Z INFO - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 2 Seconds
2023-09-28T11:43:22.613Z INFO - Starting container for site
2023-09-28T11:43:22.614Z INFO - docker run -d --expose=8000 --name censored-app-web-app_0_f98214f0 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=censored-app-web-app -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e PORT=8000 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=censored-app-web-app.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=eb80censoredid -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=False censored-user/censored-app-v1:latest

2023-09-28T11:43:22.615Z INFO - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2023-09-28T11:43:23.486Z ERROR - Container start failed for censored-web-app_0_f98214f0 with System.AggregateException, One or more errors occurred. (Docker API responded with status code=BadRequest, response={"message":"failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: \"./censored-app\": stat ./censored-app: no such file or directory: unknown"}
)
InnerException: Docker.DotNet.DockerApiException, Docker API responded with status code=BadRequest, response={"message":"failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: \"./censored-app\": stat ./censored-app: no such file or directory: unknown"}


2023-09-28T11:43:23.727Z INFO - Stopping site censored-web-app because it failed during startup.
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM rust AS builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install llvm-dev libclang-dev clang autoconf automake autotools-dev g++ gcc build-essential -y

RUN make clean
RUN make build

FROM ubuntu:22.04

ARG build_number=dev
ENV BUILD_NUMBER=${build_number}

WORKDIR /home/app
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/censored-app-dir/target/release/censored-app . 

ENV BUILD_NUMBER=${build_number}
RUN chmod +x ./censored-app

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT [ "./censored-app" ]
```

My Terraform:

```
data "external" "env" {
  program = ["sh", "${path.module}/env.sh"]
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.73.0"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}


resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_group" {
  name     = "Censored-Ressourcegroup"
  location = "germanywestcentral"
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "service_plan" {
  name = "Censored-service-plan"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  location = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
  os_type = "Linux"
  sku_name = "B1"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "web_app" {
  name = "censored-web-app"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  location =  azurerm_service_plan.service_plan.location
  service_plan_id = azurerm_service_plan.service_plan.id

  site_config {
    always_on = false

    application_stack {
      docker_image_name = "censored-user/censored-v1:latest"
      # docker_registry_url = "https://registry.hub.docker.com"
      # docker_registry_username = "cesored-user"
      # docker_registry_password = "***"
    }
  }
}
```

I already tried:

1. **Running locally**

   - Build docker container on M1 Mac. -> Docker container worked as expected
   - Build docker container on M1 Mac for x86, run through Rosetta -> Docker container worked as expected
   - Build docker container on x86 Ubuntu Desktop -> Container worked as expected
2. **Editing Dockerfile**

   - Using CMD instead of Entrypoint
   - Using ubuntu:23.01 image as running image
3. **Editing Terraform**

   - specifying docker_registry_url, docker_registry_username, docker_registry_password and having image public
   - Not specifying these parameters
4. **Deploying Manually via Azure Portal**

   - Docker image worked as expected
5. **Deploying on different, completely new, Azure Account**

   - Issue persisted

Comment: Your error message indicates that the docker container cannot find the executable file for your web app. This is because you are copying the executable file from the builder container to the production container using the COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/censored-app-dir/target/release/censored-app . command in your Dockerfile. However, the builder container is using the rust image, while the production container is using the ubuntu:22.04 image. This means that the executable file that is copied from the builder container to the production container will not be compatible with the production.

Comment: To fix this error, you need to compile the executable file for the **ubuntu:22.04 image** in the builder container.  Try adding `RUN make build --target=ubuntu-22.04` in your **docker file**.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The behavior for the target flag is not defined in the make file. Further the container works in non azure environments and even in azure environments when it is not deployed with terraform.
I edited the question to clarify that i meant building and running the docker container locally.

Comment: I also tried with your Dockerfile but it's failing to create a image, kindly delete the image and redeploy and check.

Comment: I would find that this is expected, since I have not provided the Makefile or any other of the business logic. However, tried removing the image and rebuilding it, still no different results.